# Trouble with output. Error exact fetch is less than rows returned?

Tags: sql, plsql

I am brand new to PL/SQL and I am having trouble with the output of this code.  I have a populated employee table that contains the employee name, job, pay, id, etc.  What I need is for my output to display as following:

```
Employee Name:       Johnson
Job:                 Service Writer
Total Pay:           $32,000
```

I keep getting the error exact fetch returns more than rows requested

```
ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Please enter the Employee ID:'

DECLARE
   v_eid     employee.employee_id%TYPE := &p_1;
   v_name    employee.employee_name%TYPE;
   v_job     employee.job%TYPE;
   v_pay     employee.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT employee_name, job, salary
   INTO v_name, v_job, v_pay
   FROM employee;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name: ' || v_name);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job: ' || v_job);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Pay: ' || v_pay);
END;
```

I think I am close?  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT` statement returns more than one row which means the `SELECT INTO` statement will fail with your "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" error.

Try adding a WHERE clause that will mean the SELECT statement will only ever return one row. I'm guessing by your code, you want to do something like this:

```
ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Please enter the Employee ID:'

DECLARE
   v_eid     employee.employee_id%TYPE := &p_1;
   v_name    employee.employee_name%TYPE;
   v_job     employee.job%TYPE;
   v_pay     employee.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT employee_name, job, salary
   INTO v_name, v_job, v_pay
   FROM employee
   WHERE employee_id = v_eid;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name: ' || v_name);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job: ' || v_job);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Pay: ' || v_pay);
END;
```

Check out http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01422.php for more info regarding the error.

Comment: what if I want to save more than one values? how should the variables be declared then?